# Adobe Air Mobile startup

Tags: mobile, air, adobe

I am working on an application that runs on Adobe Air for Mobile. On every Android phone I have deployed to there is SEVERE latency on startup.  The screen goes BLACK for anywhere between 10 and 30 seconds.  Putting a splash screen on doesn't help much at all.   Looks like it is taking the AIR runtime some time to bootstrap itself.

Does anyone have a work around for this?   I was thinking of writing native "wrappers" for the app that will show some sort of pseudo status and splash while the real app is loading in the background.

I had started down the "phone gap" JQM path but was very unhappy with some of the issues with JQM.  Maybe just a straight HTML5 (sans JQM) would work better than AIR?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, although I was only experiencing a 6 second delay and this mostly went away after the first time the app loaded. In the end I wrote a preloader for the app that displays a splash screen. Not a perfect solution but the best I could do without putting together a native wrapper. I've posted the preloader here: http://www.handyspoon.com/blog/air-mobile-loading-time-and-splash-screen-preloader-partial-solution/

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on Music Player using Adobe Air for Mobile and the black screen I'm seeing only lasts for about 5 seconds which is almost the same as the lag when opening the GMail app on the same device.

I'm testing on Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 running Honeycomb. Would you care to share what devices you're testing on?  My app is structured as a tabbed application and the first tab doesn't do much. It just loads a bunch of images for display.

Have you considered moving other heavy processing after the screen has loaded? If you can give us additional details on what you're doing during startup time then maybe we can give more specific suggestions. Thanks.